# Failed to get message attachments and shares from facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api to get user message

I try to get shares object from messages sent between two users.

According to Facebook documentation I should use the method /{message-id}/shares https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/message/shares

But when I tried this with a user with read_mailbox permission I get the following error:

{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
        "type": "GraphMethodException", 
        "code": 100
    }
}
so what I have to do to get shares and attachments
thanx in advanced